# Copy Node Set-Up into Notepad or any Text-Editor

Tags: node-editor

When I was exploring Unreal Engine, copying node-setups allows you to paste it into a text editor in a form of I don't know? Scripts? right into notepad so you can paste it later if you needed to while keeping the layout and style as you last saw it so you can paste it anytime later. Does blender support this? or should I enable something? or is there an add-on for this?

Comment: Hi. Can you explain your overall goal? Are you just trying to re-use node setups in different files/materials? There may be a better way of doing it than trying to copy them into the text editor if we know what you're trying to do.

Comment: The nodes are stored in the materials. You can import materials from other blend files in the File>Append menu.

Comment: There are times that I only need certain operations or layout of nodes into my new canvas, exporting and importing the blend file is a tedious task for me, I find it more convenient if I have a folder of text files with naming conventions for specific nodes setups so that I'm not limited to the blend file and jump from different windows instead, It is more like Node-to-Code since its open-source, but not internal integration. I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: It's more like saving a chunk of your setup since your node setup is created for certain task but there are chunks in your nodes that common and can be reused later so I don't have to import a blend file delete nodes that I don't need then continue.